# How to use on premise sharepoint license in Azure/Aws

Tags: sharepoint-server, aws

We are planning on migrating on premises SharePoint 2013 to AWS.

AWS provides Bring your own license feature.

How we can move this existing license and use in AWS EC2 instances?

Can anyone please share detailed steps or reference link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just create a new farm in AWS. You can use your existing license key. As users are licensed by a single CAL, you only need 1 CAL (Standard or Standard+Enterprise) per user no matter how many farms they use.

Each SharePoint server requires as server license, as well, however you can use 'trial' licensing or if you're under an EA, just move your servers before the EA renews so you claim a similar number of servers in your true-up.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  As you said, SharePoint license costs only on CAL per user, we are using sharepoint for only document storage purpose and not exposing to any intranet/internet users. we have total 20 users  for testing , development and administration purpose. Does this mean, are we paying the license for only 20 CALs. Does this CAL depend on any other parameters like storage / features.  Thanks